# How to make this query using Prometheus?

Tags: database, grafana, prometheus

I'm really new to Prometheus and for the moment I want to do some tests with the query to be a bit more familiar with it.

So with the query `container_last_seen[10s]`  it returns me an array :

```
container_last_seen{container_label_com_docker_compose_config_hash="dc8a2ab1347ad16ab37ff0ad03f3a00f86b381ea2d85d45a11367331526c3640",container_label_com_docker_compose_container_number="1",container_label_com_docker_compose_oneoff="False",container_label_com_docker_compose_project="dockprom",container_label_com_docker_compose_service="cadvisor",container_label_com_docker_compose_version="1.10.0",container_label_org_label_schema_group="monitoring",id="/docker/2b448d19a33b50411941a55435b03f5a4af19e3b3e9581054a67e4da3363ef19",image="google/cadvisor:v0.24.1",instance="cadvisor:8080",job="cadvisor",name="cadvisor"}
```

And I want to get only the attribute `name`.
So my idea was to do something like this:

```
container_last_seen[10s][name]
```

But I have a parse error. So how can I make this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem a little counterintuitive for this purpose, but the [aggregation operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) allow reducing labels with the `by` and `without` clauses.

```
sum by(name) (container_last_seen{..criteria..})
```

should get you closer to what you are wanting by returning objects with only the name key.

I think you want a little further though - you don't want values and you don't want the object part - you just want strings. Unfortunately Prometheus deals with numeric metrics that can have labels, and specifically not string metrics.

While it requires additional software, it is officially recommended by Prometheus so I will mention it here as it gets you very close to what I believe is your desired solution:

If you were to chart that query in Grafana, either with all the keys or just the name key, the legend format `{{name}}` should get you exactly what you want. Grafana also provides [label_values](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#templated-queries) to help with this purpose in regards to filtering.

Lastly if this is not the right direction for you, for intensive string-based metrics ELK/EFK stack may be a better fit. There are projects like [prometheus-es-exporter](https://github.com/braedon/prometheus-es-exporter) that can report the results from ElasticSearch queries as metrics.

Comment: Such a nice and complete answer ! Yes the goal was to display all the names in Grafana. Now I'm a bit more confident with Prometheus and Grafana since I use them for 2months. Thank you for the nice input

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad you wanted the Grafana direction. They are really awesome tools and only get better as we get past the learning curves. :) Apparently I cut off the end of my answer so I'm going to edit that back in.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as labels like 'name' are separate to the metric value. You should look at the JSON the query and query_range endpoints return to see how this is exposed.

Comment: I don't really understand the end of your answer but why I can't access the labels that the query returns ? It returns me a JSON object so I should be able to access items no ?